# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList.....] couldn't find "libdetection_based_tracker.so"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting this error when I am trying to run OpenCV sample for face detection. I have set Android SDK path and NDK path. android.mk file and Application.mk file is also set. I am not understanding why I am getting this error. Please help.

Android.mk

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    #OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
    #OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off
    #OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
    ifdef OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK
     ifneq ("","$(wildcard $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK)/OpenCV.mk)")
      include ${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/OpenCV.mk
     else
      include ${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
  endif
  else
  include C:/Users/m/Downloads/opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
endif

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-25
```

Local.properties

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\m\\Documents\\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\\android-ndk-r13b
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\m\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk1
```

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 5):

Make sure this block exists in the openCVSamplefacedetection build.gradle file:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
         path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you have the PATH to your Android NDK exported to your environment variables.